# image not appearing on web page

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to display an image on my home page. MY Index.cshtml code looks as follows:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>

<h4>View results by:</h4>
<ul id="friend">
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Countries", "Countries", "Home")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Events", "Events", "Home")</li>
</ul>
<div>
<img id="banner" src="oly1.jpg"/>
</div>
```

For some reason, though, the image does not show on my page. I have the image saved to my desktop, and when I did the same thing for another project (using an image saved to the desktop), it worked with the same syntax. I was using pure html, though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is your `oly1.jpg` localted in your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>

<h4>View results by:</h4>
<ul id="friend">
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Countries", "Countries", "Home")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Events", "Events", "Home")</li>
</ul>
<div>
    <img id="banner" src="@Url.Content("~/oly1.jpg")"/>
</div>
```

`~` refers to the root of your web site.  If you have your image file at the root, then use the above path.  If your image is inside `Content/images`, use `~/Content/images/oly1.jpg`.

Example:

[image: screenhost]

Comment: thanks. I have the image saved to my desktop; how do I import it into the images?

Comment: Right-click on the folder you'd like to import the image to.  I would suggest using `Content/images`.  Select `Add->Existing Item`, and then select the file on your desktop.

Comment: Got it! Realized I just needed to use "add existing item" instead of new item.